# get 2 elements by preg_match from a html file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

can't understand how it works preg_match, tryed today few hours to create my function with lot of examples, even documentation and didnt help me. so need yours help please.

need te get 2 elements

first is element name **menu**, secound is content between tags {main}
looks like

```
{main item=menu} bla bla bla{/main}
```

Comment: It would probably be more useful to you if you showed what you tried. This way we can explain if there was something wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple regex would be `/\{([a-z]+)\s*item=([a-z]+)\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/`. Applied to your example, this would return the matching groups `main`, `menu` and `bla bla bla`.

```
if (preg_match('/\{([a-z]+)\s*item=([a-z]+)\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/', $data, $m)) {
    if ($m[2] == 'menu') {
        // do something usefull..
        $content = $m[3];
    }
}
```

you could even use `preg_match_all`, to iterate over all elements, matching this pattern.

Comment: '/{loop item=([a-z]+)\}(.*?){\/loop}/s' is working, thanks